# Showing shipping costs in the cart page

Tags: commerce

Hi i'm using the Commerce Shipping Postal Code Weight module. It works fine but I just want to get shipping costs in the cart page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal StackExchange! Since this is an open forum, your best bet to get help is to make your question as clear and detailed as possible. It is not clear from your question what exactly is the problem you're having... also, let us know what solutions you've tried already. See [this post for more info](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Rachid , This might help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100747/im-looking-for-a-drupal-commerce-shipping-in-cart-estimate

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wanting something like [Commerce Cart Estimate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_estimate).